# Is it too much overhead if ResultSet could be used to getBinaryStream() but wasn't to?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In mysql I have table

```
CREATE  TABLE `articles_attachments` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `size` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  `article_id` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
  `contents` LONGBLOB NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_file` (`article_id` ASC, `name` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_article` (`article_id` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

In application code I often need to just list attachments, but don't get their contents. So when I retrieve rows from that table I don't want resources wasted to serve "content" field.
Tricky part is that I use custom library which does "SELECT * FROM articles_attachments", so it queries to return all fields.

What I can easily do is to override RowMapper (comes from Spring Jdbc) and just don't map "content" field (do not call ResultSet.getBinaryStream).

**Question**: Will that help to avoid resource waste?... I don't want 100 stream to be opened when I retrieve 100 rows of attachments table.

Comment: How about creating a view without the `contents` field and having your library generate a `select *` query for it?

Comment: Good alternative, thank you. But still, I'm really interested - am I wasting resources even if not calling getBinaryStream()

Comment: As far as I know (but I haven't verified this), in the MySQL protocol all data for all selected columns is streamed inline after the execute. So if you don't need some piece of data (especially something large like a blob), then you shouldn't select it. Note that this doesn't apply to all database systems (most don't fetch blobs inline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did couple tests and it turns out that answer is "Yes, you waste resources (specifically bandwidth) if resulting query contains fields of ~BLOB type even if you don't call ResultSet.getBinaryStream".

I did tested it with:

- MySQL 5.6.20 & MirandaDB 10.0.13
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar
- HikariCP-java6-2.2.5.jar